# XSD - how can I require a number of elements in a complexType, in any order, but also allow any other elements

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm trying to create an XSD schema document with conceptually simple requirements, but I've researched and tested solutions over two days with no luck. Please help!

I'm trying to require that each "item" element include a number of subelements that are required, in any order, but then also allow that "item" elements be extended with any other arbitrary subelements.

Conceptually, this is what I need:

```
<xs:element name="item">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

That is to say, both of the following should be valid:

```
<item>
  <title>Some-title</title>
  <id>1</id>
  <description>Some-description</description>
</item>

<item>
  <description>Some-description</description>
  <id>1</id>
  <title>Some-title</title>
  <customProperty>I don't care about other elements</customProperty>
</item>
```

But this should not be valid:

```
<item>
  <title>Some invalid item with no id</title>
  <description>Some-description</description>
  <otherProperty>Other properties should simply be irrelevant - I only care that all required fields are provided</otherProperty>
</item>
```

Note that I actually need about twelve specific properties, not just 'id', 'title' and 'description', but I omitted them here for brevity. The principle is the same - they should be enumerated as all being required, but in any order.

I don't control the XML - the goal is to create a loose XSD document to validate XML submissions from customers.

To me, this seems like a simple use-case, but my research hasn't led me to a solution yet.

Is this possible with XSD? Any help is appreciated!